# List Manipulation matrices

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following two lists:

List A:

```
A={{-0.0390625, 0., 0., 0., 0.0390625}, {-0.174377, -0.073478, 
  3.0893*10^-16, 0.073478, 
  0.174377}, {-0.196939, -0.112309, -1.50053*10^-16, 0.112309, 
  0.196939}, {-0.174377, -0.073478, 5.52991*10^-16, 0.073478, 
  0.174377}, {-0.0390625, 0., 0., 0., 0.0390625}}
```

List B:

```
B={{5, 6, 6, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 1, 5, 5}, {5, 4, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 5, 
  5}, {5, 0, 5,6, 5}}
```

I want to create 6 (max. value in list B) copies of List A, but if a value at point {i,j} in List B is smaller then 6, by example value X at point {i,j} in List B, then the value at point {i,j} in List A should only be used in the first X copies. Hence the last 6-X copie(s) should be zero at point {i,j}. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you show us your code so far, *then* we can try to fix it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of a decade of no feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (for convenience, I use smaller matrices)

```
n = 3;
max = 4;
A = RandomReal[1.0, {n, n}];
(B = RandomInteger[{1, max}, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
res = A UnitStep[B - #] & /@ Range@Max[B];
Column[MatrixForm /@ res]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ybeltukov's solution rules. Here's a different way to get the same result:

```
res = Table[
   A Function[val, If[val <= i, 0, 1], Listable][B],
   {i, Range[max] - 1}
   ];
Column[MatrixForm /@ res]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your requirements:

```
result=Transpose /@ 
 MapThread[{#1, #2, #3, #4, #5} &, 
  Transpose /@ MapThread[PadRight[Table[#1, {#2}], 6] &, {A, B}, 2], 
  2]
```

Visualizing:

```
Column[MatrixForm /@result]
```

yields:
[image]